# duplicate fields in a pdf - Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-java-toolkit

I have a pdf From which a user needs to fill out. There will need to be a replication of the fields based on a number entered into an earlier field (see screenshot below)

[image]

For example, if a user enters the number 3 in the voyages box, I want to be able to create 3 'copies' of the complete table below it.

Is this something that is able to be done with Javascript within the pdf? MY thinking is that it *should* be possible, but i cant find anything on the adobe forums that indicates how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate form fields in a PDF using JavaScript (Acrobat DC SDK) like this (example shows creating a button on each page):

```
var aPage = this.getPageBox();
var w = 45;         // Width of each button
var h = 12          // Height of each button
var nNavi = 4;      // Number of buttons to be placed
var g = 6;          // Gap between buttons
var totalWidth = nNavi * w + (nNavi - 1) * g; // total width of navi bar

var widthPage = aPage[2] - aPage[0];

// Horizontal offset to center navi bar
var hoffset = (widthPage - totalWidth) / 2;
var voffset = 12;          // vertical offset from bottom

for (var nPage = 0; nPage < this.numPages; nPage++) {
       // Create the fields

       var pp = this.addField("PrevPage", "button", nPage,  
                [ hoffset, voffset, hoffset + w, voffset + h ] );
       pp.buttonSetCaption(pp.name);
       pp.fillColor=color.ltGray;
       pp.setAction("MouseUp", "this.pageNum--");

       var np = this.addField("NextPage", "button", nPage,
                [ hoffset + w + g, voffset, hoffset + 2*w + g, voffset + h ] );
       np.buttonSetCaption(np.name);
       np.fillColor=color.ltGray;
       np.setAction("MouseUp", "this.pageNum++");

       var pv = this.addField("PrevView", "button", nPage,
                [ hoffset + 2*w + 2*g, voffset, hoffset + 3*w + 2*g, voffset + h ] );

       pv.buttonSetCaption(pv.name);
       pv.fillColor=color.ltGray;
       pv.setAction("MouseUp", "app.goBack()");

       var nv = this.addField("NextView", "button", nPage,
           [ hoffset + 3*w + 3*g, voffset, hoffset + 4*w + 3*g, voffset + h ] );

       nv.buttonSetCaption(nv.name);
       nv.fillColor=color.ltGray;
       nv.setAction("MouseUp", "app.goForward()");
}
```

[[Source](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_AcrobatForms%2FCreating_forms.htm&rhsearch=Using%20Javascript%20in%20forms&rhsyns=%20)]

The [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_AcrobatForms%2FMultiple_customized_forms_within_a_form_based_on_user_input.htm&rhsearch=Using%20Javascript%20in%20forms&rhsyns=%20) also notes the following:

> **Multiple customized forms within a form based on user input**
>
> Subforms may also be subject to conditions. For example, form fields for dependent children would become visible if the user checks a box indicating that there are dependent children. In addition, XFA allows multiple form fields with the same name and multiple copies of the same form.

[This page lists XFA specific methods](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_AcrobatForms%2FXFA-specific_JavaScript_methods.htm&rhsearch=Using%20Javascript%20in%20forms&rhsyns=%20) that you may find useful in this effort.